# Filter a table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The following data set is given (in reality much more cases):

```
data_test = data.frame(ID = c ("1","2","3","4","5"),
              product = c("A","B","C","A","C"),
              milieu = c("good","medium","bad","medium","bad"),
              online = c(1,0,1,1,0),
              ooh = c(0,1,0,1,1),
              event = c(1,1,0,0,0))
```

Now I want to built a shiny app where someone can choose a milieu lets say "good" and  a product "A" and all online which have "1" and the data table with these settings is given back. In the Example ID 1.

I tried the following

ui:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("product milieu"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("select",
                 selectInput("select_milieu",
                             label = "Milieu",
                 choices = list("good",
                                "medium",
                                "bad")
                 ),
                 selectInput("select_product", 
                             label = "Product",
                             choices = list("A", 
                                            "B", 
                                            "C")
                 ),
                 selectInput("select_online", 
                             label = "Online",
                             choices = list(1, 
                                            0)
                 ),
                 selectInput("select_ooh", 
                             label = "ooh",
                             choices = list(1, 
                                            0)
                 ),
                 selectInput("select_Event", 
                             label = "Event",
                             choices = list(1, 
                                            0)

                 )
    ),
    mainPanel("My table",
              textOutput("output_milieu"),
              textOutput("output_product"),
              textOutput("output_event"),
              textOutput("output_online"),
              textOutput("output_ooh"),
              tableOutput("gapminder_table")
              )
  )
))
```

server:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$gapminder_table <- renderTable({ 
    subset(data_test,
           milieu == input$select_milieu & product == input$select_product &
             online == input$select_online)

  })
  output$output_milieu <- renderText({
    paste("milieu", input$select_milieu)
  })
  output$output_product <- renderText({
    paste("product", input$select_product)
  })
  output$output_event <- renderText({
    paste("Event", input$select_Event)
  })
  output$output_online <- renderText({
    paste("Online", input$select_Online)
  })
  output$output_ooh <- renderText({
    paste("out of Home", input$select_ooh)
  })

})
```

My problem is now how to filter for "event" and "ooh". Does anyone has an advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just do all of the filtering in the same `renderTable()` step?

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're not showing the table you're making with that `renderTable()` step? Did you mean to have a `tableOutput("gapminder_table")` line in your ui?

Comment: Sorry I forgot this during copy/paste...

How would you do the filtering in renderTable()??

Comment: The same way you're doing it now. I'll post an answer so you can see what I mean.

Comment: On a side note: `?subset` is intended for interactive use. See the warning section in the help file. It might be better to use `[` or for example dplyr's `filter_` function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make this much simpler if you begin to explore the [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) package for datatables with shiny.  With this, you can just type in whatever filter criteria you like above the respective columns.

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

data_test = data.frame(ID = c ("1","2","3","4","5"),
                       product = c("A","B","C","A","C"),
                       milieu = c("good","medium","bad","medium","bad"),
                       online = c(1,0,1,1,0),
                       ooh = c(0,1,0,1,1),
                       event = c(1,1,0,0,0))

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    output$gapminder_table <- renderDataTable({ 
        data_test        
    },
    filter = 'top',
    rownames = FALSE)    
})
```

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("product milieu"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel("Place for other criteria"
        ),
        mainPanel("My table",
                  dataTableOutput("gapminder_table")
        )
    )
))
```

Comment: This is pretty simple!